# How to implement PADES signature in iTextSharp 5?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I am currently using iTextSharp 5 to apply digital signatures to PDFs. I am applying signatures in the detached mode by using the support of BouncyCastle, like this:

```
public void Sign(PDFDocument doc, SigningKey key)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(doc.Content))
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, memStream, '\0'))
    {
        PdfSignatureAppearance signature = stamper.SignatureAppearance;

        IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(key.ToParameters(), DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
        MakeSignature.SignDetached(signature, pks, key.CertChain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);

        doc.Content = memStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I found out that `CryptoStandard` allows me to choose the standard for my digital signature, but the only ones I see are `CADES` and `CMS`, and I also require support for PADES. Is it possible to do it in iTextSharp?

Comment: PAdES signatures (except the ISO 32000-1 compatibility profile) require a specially profiled CAdES signature container. That's why the `CryptoStandard` is called `CADES`, it is for generating some flavor of PAdES signatures.

Comment: So CADES includes PADES, and it depends on how I configure my signature?

Comment: *"So CADES includes PADES"* - more exactly the iText `CryptoStandard` value `CADES` is *only* for creating PAdES signatures. iText is a PDF library, its security API is not meant to create arbitrary CAdES signatures, it's only meant to generate PAdES signatures (and ol'fashioned ISO 32000-1 interoperable signatures with more generic CMS containers).

Comment: Did my answer help? Or are there still open questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PAdES

First off, you say you *require support for PADES* but you don't mention which PAdES profile you need.

PAdES originally (in 2009/2010) was specified as an ETSI technical specification (ETSI TS 102 778 parts 1-6) with profiles

- PAdES Basic - PAdES-CMS Profile based on ISO 32000-1
- PAdES Enhanced - PAdES-BES and PAdES-EPES Profile
- Long Term - PAdES-LTV Profile
- PAdES for XML Content - Profiles for XAdES signatures of XML documents embedded in
  PDF Containers

Meanwhile (2016) it has been updates as an European Standard (ETSI EN 319 142 parts 1-2) with profiles

- PAdES baseline signatures at levels B-B, B-T, B-LT, and B-LTA
- Profile for CMS digital signatures in PDF
- Extended PAdES signature profiles at levels PAdES-E-BES, PAdES-E-EPES, and PAdES-E-LTV
- Profiles for XAdES Signatures signing XML content in PDF

(the latter three being re-christianed versions of the old profiles but the baseline profiles being in focus now).

#### iText 5.5.x

As you found out the iText enumeration `CryptoStandard` knows two options `CMS` and `CADES`.

First of all, `CADES` is *not* for generating arbitrary CAdES signatures but for generating specially profiled CAdES signature containers and embedding them in PDFs as is required for non-CMS-profile PAdES signatures.

Concerning your question, therefore

> I also require support for PADES. Is it possible to do it in iTextSharp?

Yes, iText 5.5.x does support simple PAdES profiles. In particular you'll use the `CryptoStandard` values for following profiles:

- `CryptoStandard.CMS` for the profile for CMS digital signatures in PDF;
- `CryptoStandard.CADES` for baseline signatures at level B-B and B-T and for extended ones at levels PAdES-E-BES and PAdES-E-EPES.